# Use a map for module attribute accumulate: true

Tags: elixir

I can register a module attribute with the option accumulate as true like this

```
 Module.register_attribute __MODULE__, :structs, accumulate: true


  for line <- [%{"some" => %{"test1" => 1, "test2" => 2}}, %{"some" => %{"test1" => 3, "test2" => 4}}] do
    @structs %Struct{
        some: line["some"]
      }
  end
```

Then I have the following list.

```
[
  %Test.Struct{some: %{"test1" => 3, "test2" => 4}},
  %Test.Struct{some: %{"test1" => 1, "test2" => 2}}
]
```

But what if I want to have a map? How can this be achieved?

I tried the following thing to define `@tests[v]` but wont work

```
  Module.register_attribute __MODULE__, :tests, accumulate: true

  @moduledoc """
  for line <- [%{"some" => %{"test1" => 1, "test2" => 2}}, %{"some" => %{"test1" => 3, "test2" => 4}}] do
    Enum.each(line["some"], fn {k, v} ->
      @tests[v] %Struct{
          some: k
      }
    end)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. `accumulate: true` creates the *list* and this is [hardcoded](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.5/lib/elixir/lib/module.ex#L1107).

The only possible solution would be to produce different variables with [`Module.register_attribute/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#register_attribute/3) and use [`Module.put_attribute/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#put_attribute/3) to update variables dynamically.

Comment: So the only solution would be using a macro right? to have different variables for each map k

Comment: I doubt I understand why would you need a macro? `Module.register_attribute` accepts a dynamic name of the variable.

Comment: You might use [`Module.put_attribute/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#put_attribute/3) to create and update variables having dynamic names.

Comment: How could you dynamically access these attribute from a function within the same module? get_attribute returns "could not call get_attribute with argument Talkyng.MediaTopics because the module is already compiled"

Comment: One cannot access attributes in runtime, they are inlined _by compiler_. Since macros are also inlined by the compiler, you might use a macro as an accessor, but in general, that should not be needed.

Comment: The thing is, if I know how the attribute is called, I can access it through @content_es for example, but if I created it dynamically, cant I access it through Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, String.to_atom("content_#{lang}"))?

Comment: Sure you can, but **only in compile time**. Attributes do not exist in runtime, they are **inlined by compiler**.

Comment: I mean, in this example https://paiza.io/projects/-mIjqaTEgQEIwFcQPlC32Q?language=elixir how can I access  foo_en but receive an already compiler error by using get_attribute? if its only on compile time, is it possible to access it same way foo_en but without knowing the attr's name? having to build it through a param for example?

Comment: You should understand what is _compilation time_ vs _runtime_ and specifically how they differ. I have posted the corrected code with explanations https://paiza.io/projects/e/MQ6DuPkvyB5gPcxitERvWQ?theme=twilight